# Facebook comments box for site loading very slowly

Tags: social-network

Hi I'm using a Facebook comments module for my Drupal 6 website on aws.

I've noticed that especially during mobile visits the loading of the Facebook comments box is last and is slowing down the page load time.

How do I find out if this comment Facebook code is loading asynchronously and how to speed it up? Any way to update the Facebook comments module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your phone's browser to the Developer Tools on your computer. Check the network tab and check what's slowing down the requests.

It might be that you have too many requests, and the comment requests are being given a lower priority in order to render the actual page first.

Here are the links for Android and iOS

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

For Apple's link, go down to the section named '*Safari on iOS*'

---

Safari's network tab 
[image: Safari's Network Tab]

Chrome's network tab
[image: Chrome's network tab]